# How to revert code if accidentally reverted to checkout on Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I accidentally reverted code to previous checkpoint which was like a week ago. Is there a way to reverse the code back to the non-autosaved copy?

Comment: did you manage to revert code? I made the the same mistake and i dont know how to go back.

Comment: Nope I had to start all over...

Comment: sadly, even i had to start all over.